# Variable type of template argument

Tags: pointers, boost, c++17, variadic-templates

I tried to use an arbitrary pointer to a member of the structure ... But nothing works;

*Code1:*

```
template <
        typename Structure,

        template <typename... Args>
        typename Wrapper,

        template <typename... Args>
        typename Wrapper2,

        typename... Args1,
        void Structure::* ... Args2>
    auto MembersContructer(Wrapper<Args1...> wrapper1, Wrapper2<Args2...> wrapper2)
        -> TypesContainer<mi::member<Structure, Args1, Args2>...>;
```

**void Structure::* ... Args2**

And I tried to use "variadic type of variadic type") That is

*Code2:*

```
 template <
        typename Structure,

        template <typename... Args>
        typename Wrapper,

        template <typename... Args>
        typename Wrapper2,

        typename... Args1,
        (Args1 Structure::*) ... Args2>
    auto MembersContructer(Wrapper<Args1...> wrapper1, Wrapper2<Args2...> wrapper2)
        -> TypesContainer<mi::member<Structure, Args1, Args2>...>;
```

**(Args1 Structure::*) ... Args2**

Hope someone can figure out what I want.

Comment: A pointer to a *data* member or a pointer to a member *function*? Either way, why does `Wrapper2` have a list of typenames, not a list of non-type template parameters? What is `Wrapper` and its `Args1...`?

Comment: My best guess is that you want [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OeDZnRMGlSEdiKRZ)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, this is an inattentive mistake, but it turned out it worked. I was confused that VSCode highlighted the Args1...So it's a little strange - it works, but VSCode thinks it is wrong. But thanks, I have never read about "auto" in templates. It is very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Using [c++17 placeholder auto for non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

```
template <
    template <typename... Args> typename Wrapper,
    template <auto... Args> typename Wrapper2,
    typename... Args1,
    auto... Args2
>
auto MembersContructer(Wrapper<Args1...> wrapper1, Wrapper2<Args2...> wrapper2);
```

Notice that there's no need to store `Structure`.